# How to find out the font size of window caption?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, caption

I am creating a custom window in WPF. For this I would like to get the current font size of the window caption (whatever the user has chosen in *Window Color and Appearance* settings). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is to use `SystemFonts.CaptionFontSizeKey`.

Answer (score 5):

`System.Drawing.SystemFonts.CaptionFont` perhaps?

Comment: I have found the answer while looking around in Blend, but thank you. If I didn't find it, your answer would definitely be the way to go.